# how to print Ascii code of a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I have a string and I want to print hex value of each parts ascii code.
for example if the string is "0200" the output will be `30323030` .

and here's my code:

```
string bit_pattern;
bit_pattern = "5678008180000000";
cout << hex << bit_pattern;
```

but it prints `5678008180000000` instead of `35363738303038313830303030303030`
how do i fix it???

Comment: For each `char` in the string, convert to `unsigned int` and sent to a `hex` - manipulated `cout`.

Comment: I'm sure you can cast it or convert it to hashCode(). There is a connection between hashcode and ascii

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following

```
for (int i=0; i<bit_pattern.length(); i++)
    cout << hex << (int)bit_pattern[i];
```

to print the ascii value (in hex format) char by char.

Answer (score 1):

You're just sending the same `std::string` right to `std::cout`. Just sending the `hex` manipulator isn't going to magically convert all those chars.

I admit this is complete overkill, but I was bored:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

class ascicodes
{
    std::ostringstream ss;

public:
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const ascicodes& obj)
    {
        os << obj.ss.str();
        return os;
    }

    ascicodes(const std::string& s)
    {
        ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
        std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(),
            [this](char ch)
            {
                ss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned int>(ch);
            });
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::string bit_pattern = "5678008180000000";
    std::cout << ascicodes(bit_pattern) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ascicodes("A completely different string") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
35363738303038313830303030303030
4120636f6d706c6574656c7920646966666572656e7420737472696e67
```

Comment: @DieterLücking yeah I forgot it i the class actually. i intended it there.  you think she's better in main and just go with decimal in the class ? It has to be prior-to-value-insertion, only reason I mention it.

Comment: And how to convince a person that this is better than short sample from *herohuyongtao* using old C-style conversion but still producing the correct result ?

Comment: @SChepurin I didn't know I had to convince anyone it was "better"; only that it was one way to do it, particularly if you need to do it frequently and in tons of code with preexisting stream outputs. Also, his sample doesn't handle high-ascii. the sign extension will not be pleasant for chars above 127.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I think, this can be counted as "convincing enough".

Comment: @DieterLücking is `std::hex` sticky? I can never remember which is and is not (besides `setw`, which is *not* (if I remember right). They two difference streams so it still has to be in the class, but was just curious.

Comment: @WhozCraig It is (and I do not like that)